# Why does eth0 disappear when I set a static IP (server 12.10)?

Tags: 12.10, server, static-ip

For some reason, if I try to set a static IP address, my eth0 disappears from `ifconfig`'s output. I am running Ubuntu server 12.10 on a gateway laptop.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

It then gives this output when I run `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:b8ff:fee7:f71c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:352 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31874 (31.8 KB)  TX bytes:45369 (45.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:41740 (41.7 KB)  TX bytes:41740 (41.7 KB)
```

When I change to static:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.37
       netmask 225.225.225.0
       gateway 192.168.1.1
```

...then run a `service networking restart`, I only get the loopback block from `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:41740 (41.7 KB)  TX bytes:41740 (41.7 KB)
```

However, I *can* force a static IP with `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.37 netmask 255.255.255.0` but obviously this goes away on a reboot.

Why will one way work but not the other? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the output change if you enter `ifup eth0`? What is the output of `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: @qbi - `ifup eth0` gives `Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "192.168.1.37/255.255.255.0".` and `ifconfig -a` shows all devices (eth0 lo wlan0) except the "inet addr" and "inet6 addr" lines are missing from all but the loopback block. Also the wlan0 block has zeroes in the RX and TX areas, since i have it switched off.

Comment: Oh, forgot to ask: How do you set those values, i.e. which file do you open or which GUI program do you use?

Comment: No gui installed. I've been editing the /etc/network/interfaces file directly with nano. I work at the console on my laptop for networking stuff and ssh in from my desktop for other stuff.

Comment: In your original question you write `netmask 225.225.225.0`. Is the 225 a typo? It seems strange for a netmask.

Comment: wow, undone by a typo. this is why i should proofread harder :(

problem solved: it was my bad for mistyping my netmask in the interfaces file. thanks for spotting it qbi

Answer (score 10):

It was a typo. I should have had 255.255.255.0 as my netmask and instead typed 225.225.225.0

Thanks to qbi for helping me see the error of my ways

Comment: it is so easy to look at these numbers, and think they are reasonable.

Comment: This is a very common error, and difficult to spot. Our eyes see what we expect to see.

Answer (score -2):

Do not do `service networking restart`; it is deprecated.

Instead do `ifdown eth0` and then `ifup eth0` or simply reboot.

Comment: Those do not solve my problem. I also didn't know the service reset was deprecated; i was using `/etc/init.d/networking restart` before, and my system told me to use `service networking restart` instead

Comment: Yikes, I always thought reboots are the bane of any Linux aficionado? After all it's why we shun those Windows folks, isn't it?